# Rails not executing javascript from respond_to block

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having an issue with rails not actually executing JS in a template. I have a respond to block in my controller that is like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.js   {}      
end
```

and the proper file in the views, but when it renders it actually just prints the JS, like the mime type is wrong. (the file is `add_item.js.erb`)

For example if I had this as a test in my view:

```
<%= "alert('running');" %>
```

but when that action gets executed in the controller the page redirects and the HTML out put is the JS itself:

```
alert('running');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to comment on the author's answer but there's too much code to post... You could tighten up the JS a little. First you probably want to set headers globally and not on every request and if you're making a post you need to do a little more work:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function(event, xhr, settings) {
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript, application/javascript");     
});
```

Using [getScript](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getScript) would also make the code shorter:

```
$("a.add_line_item").click(function() {
  .getScript(this.href); 
});
```

I also have a [blog post](http://gaskell.org/unobtrusive-deleting-with-rails-and-jquery/) about making post requests from jQuery to Rails that you might be interested in.

Comment: Excellent answer. this really cleaned my code up nicely. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This behaviour of Rails is correct. However you do not provide how you call this JS page in your view (`link_to_remote` ?)

What most people forget is that other JS helper methods (`link_to_remote` etc) perform `eval(response)`. If you write custom JavaScript (like I did with jQuery) you have to add `eval(...)` by yourself.

**EDIT** Here an example:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "foo",
  type: 'post',
  success: function(data) {
    eval(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: right, I did write my own jQuery for this, where do you use the `eval(...)` method? do did you encapsulate your js with it?

Comment: I added an example for how to use `eval()` in jQuery's `$.ajax` to match the behaviour of standard Rails JS helpers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<%= "alert('running');" %>
</script>
```

Not sure what you're trying to do, but you can't simply load some javascript text code in a browser and expect it to run.

Comment: Nope, that's not working, and sure you can just load some JS into your browser and it should run, I don't understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling that action? Are you using an :update option in a remote helper?

I've seen it behave this way if you are using a remote helper with an :update option set and then trying to send back a specific replace_html or similar call using rjs on the controller side.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, It was a JS problem, I'm using the ajax method that jQuery provides as such.

```
$("a.add_line_item").click( function() {
  $.ajax({
    url: this.href,
    dataType: "script",
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript");},
  });
 return false;
});
```